# Best reconstruction loss for RGB images?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-functions, image-processing

Which loss works the best for pixel-wise RGB image `(3, width, height)`reconstruction loss?

It seems there are several options

1. Regression way. The input image has dimension `(3, width, height)` with values `[0,1]`. Apply `sigmoid` to the last layer in the generative (CNN) layer such that the output image has pixel values `[0,1]` for each channel, and simply use pixel-wise L1 (or L2) loss.
2. Multi-class cross entropy way - treat each channel as one of 255 classes. Apply `softmax` to the last layer and use `cross entropy` loss to predict the class label `[0,255]`.

What is the de facto loss for rgb image reconstructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option is sensible as it's the usual MAE/MSE and they're used as reconstruction loss in may other situations. You can also use cross entropy loss for $w\times h\times 3$ values.

I do not recommend your second option as the class labels destroys the ordinal relationship between the pixel values, i.e. $0<1\dots<255$.

Comment: Also wondering, does sigmoid affect the regression performance on the output [0,1] range? Sigmoid clips the values to be within [0,1], but the values don't linearly change from 0 to 1 due to sigmoid. It seems the values will be more saturated at 0 and 1.

Comment: If the target values are between 0-1, you should use some sort of activation in any case. Being non-linear is of little importance.